Subdivide Surface Shadow Problem
I added a line to the cylinder part. and I added a subdivision surface. the lines I added are shadowed, why is that?

this is the original version without lines and smooth shadows.


Did you use a setting of Shade Smooth or Auto Smooth before adding the edge loops? Is it still present after reapplying the Shade Smooth/Auto Smooth?

no I didn't use shade smooth I just used subdivide surface. I put this cylinder as an example. it's actually an airplane I modeled.

The original cylinder is not really a cylinder, it's a polygon (it has straight sides)
When you add lines, you're not adding them at the position that makes an actual cylinder, but a little inside.
The shadows appear because the lines are creating different curves, since they're not at an exact cylinder position.

Yes, my problem is exactly as you say. Is there a way to overcome this situation? I had to add a line to my model later, so this problem appeared. @Daniel Moller

If you are subdividing, why do you need the lines? Aren't the new lines added by the subdivider enough?

not enough. I had to add lines later to fit the topology.  @Daniel Moller

https://i.sstatic.net/MJv5g8pB.png This is actually the example I modelled. You can see the shadows @Daniel Möller

I don't know how to fix this model, but I know you don't need to create those lines, you can: "inset faces", or "apply the subdivider", or "create a cylinder with more divisions from the start"
